# I have a particular xpath for a input text box, how to access this xpath in using robotframework? //*[@id="p_0"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input

Tags: robotframework

I have the xpath from inspecting the element in chrome:

```
//*[@id="p_0"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input
```

But the same when I am passing in my robotframework code doesn't pick the XPath.

I tried giving the above mentioned xpath as:

```
xpath=//input[@id='p_0']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
```

This particular code gives me error as element not found

Answer (score 1):

The XPath you tried with is different than what inspect returned - the inspect value starts with `//*[@id='p_0']`, i.e. "whatever node name with that id", while yours is `//input[@id='p_0']` - "an `input` element with that id"; change the "input" to star.

The other thing is the locator's end/suffix - the one from the inspect ends at the "input" tag, while yours at the table cell; append the `/input` if you're targeting that element.